# Data not showing in QGIS after re-opening the file

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm pretty new to QGIS and have some problems loading content. After loading some vector and shapefiles i'd like to make a new layer myself or edit data coming from the loaded files (like clipping, dissolve etc.). Everything works normal and everything shows exactly how it has to be. But after closing the document and re-opening it later, only the loaded layers are visible, the edited layers are invisible and the attribute table is empty (which it wasn't before I closed the file).

Can somebody help / explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you save the clipped / dissolved files on your hard disk, or are they temporary files?

Comment: Did you save the the QGIS project after loading clipped / dissolved layers into QGIS?

Comment: I did save the project, but didn't save the different layers on my hard disk, I thought they would be a part of the saved document, I didn't know I had to save them separately, thank you!